How many drops of wine are there in a wine bottle?
Many years ago, I saw a video on youtube where a person takes an almost empty wine bottle and holds it upside down as the final drops come out. He asks people to place bets on how drops of wine will come out.
I was curious about this, and wondered if some mathematical model (e.g. Poisson Process) can be made to characterize this situation. In my opinion, the mathematical model would have to obey the follow conditions:

On some level, the rate is somewhat random
Initially, the rate of the wine droplets coming out is faster, but as time goes on the rate of wine droplets coming out slows down
After some time $\tau$ , there must be a zero probability of wine remaining in the bottle

Here is my attempt to write the naive model (based on a non-homogenous poisson process):
$$ N(t) \sim \text{Poisson}(\Lambda(t)) $$
Where

$N(t)$ is the number of droplets that have fallen by time $t$.

In a non-homogenous poisson process, we need a rate function that approaches infinity as $t$ approaches $\tau$:
$$ \lambda(t) = \frac{\lambda_0}{(1 - t/\tau)^\beta} $$
Where:

$\lambda_0$ is the initial rate
$\tau$ is the time at which all wine is guaranteed to have fallen
$\beta > 1$ is a shape parameter controlling how quickly the rate increases

The cumulative rate function would just be the integral of this:
$$ \Lambda(t) = \int_0^t \lambda(s) ds = \lambda_0 \tau \left(\frac{1}{(1-t/\tau)^{\beta-1}} - 1\right) / (\beta - 1) $$
In terms of the volume of wine remaining, we can write:
$$ V(t) = \max(0, V_0 - v \cdot N(t)) $$
Where:
$V_0$ is the initial volume  and $v$ is the average volume of a droplet
Does my work make sense?


Note 1: As a sanity check, I tried to plug some values into the model:

To set the parameters, let's assume:
$$ V_0 = 10 \text{ ml} $$
$$ v = 0.05 \text{ ml per droplet} $$
$$ \lambda_0 = 100 \text{ droplets per minute (initial rate)} $$
$$ \tau = 60 \text{ minutes} $$
$$ \beta = 2 $$
The expected number of droplets by time $t$ is:
$$ E[N(t)] = \Lambda(t) = 6000 \left(\frac{1}{1-t/60} - 1\right) $$
And the expected remaining volume is:
$$ E[V(t)] = \max\left(0, 10 - 0.05 \cdot 6000 \left(\frac{1}{1-t/60} - 1\right)\right) $$


Note 2: To simulate this process:

Generate waiting times between droplets:
$$ T_i \sim \text{Exponential}(\lambda(t_i)) $$
Where $t_i$ is the time of the $i$-th droplet.
The time of the $n$-th droplet:
$$ t_n = \sum_{i=1}^n T_i $$
The number of droplets by time $t$:
$$ N(t) = \max{n : t_n \leq t} $$
The remaining volume at time $t$:
$$ V(t) = \max(0, 10 - 0.05 \cdot N(t)) $$

"we need a rate function that approaches infinity as $t$ approaches $\tau$." This seems backwards. Does it make sense that the expected number of droplets $E[N(t)]$ in your sanity check should diverge as $t\rightarrow\tau$?

@JohnBarber : I think you might be correct...

Wouldn't physics play a big role in terms of what might be a good way to model such behaviors?

@ Srini: I agree, this is ultimately a physics problem. But I was curious to model it in abstraction as a mathematical process.

How about a rate that decreases with time? Something like $\lambda(t) = \lambda_0/[1+{(t/\tau)}^2]$ for instance. Then $\Lambda(t) = \lambda_0 \tau \arctan(t/\tau)$, which seems much more physical.
